# Why does python OpenCV GUI crashes in simple video circle detection program on linux?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, geometry, hough-transform

[Snapshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UWqG.png) I have been trying to detect circles in a video. I checked many tutorials and stackoverflow questions, and my code seems correct. It even compiles correctly. However it takes time to  open the GUI window, and as soon as it opens, it crashes. Here is my code is there any problem with it?

`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap  = cv2.VideoCapture('Red Motion Spin Looping Motion Background.mp4')
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret,img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5) 
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
            # draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
            # draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`
UPDATE: I followed @Micka 's advice and the window showed up. However it took forever to open and it does not go beyond the first frame of the video [screenshot of the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3LrW.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refine your question such as to show the traceback if any.

Comment: Is there any error message? after capturing: check whether img is empty before going on. Find out at which line it crashes (e.g. print something before each line).

Comment: @Micka I will post a picture of what it does by editing the question. It only says init done and does nothing after. I circled the GUI

Comment: @thewaywewere Thank you for your input. I have edited my question

Comment: what kind of gui? di you mean the opencv window? put `cv2.waitKey(1)`  within the loop after imshow, otherwise nothing will be displayed at all (opencv will render within the waitkey times).

Comment: are you able to just reproduce the video??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ No I posted a new screenshot after I added the cv2.waitKey() function

Comment: can you (for the moment) reduce your code to capturing and displaying? e.g. while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret,img = cap.read() cv2.imshow('image',img) cv2.waitKey(1) and test whether images are loaded correctly??maybe your circle detection is just very slow. What's the video's resolution?

Comment: I am guessing HoughCircles found lots of circles. Try to refine Houghcircle params to find only relevant circles.

Comment: @Micka the resolution is 640 x 360. It does display the video alone. I also ran a program to detect a specific color in the video and it runs fine

Comment: Looks like either your circle detection or drawing is extremely slow. Can you comment out the drawing pf circles and test the speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a workable code tested with `Python 2.7.12` and `OpenCV3.2.0`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture("001.mp4")
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while capture.isOpened():
    # grab the current frame and initialize the status text
    grabbed, frame = capture.read()

    if frame is not None:
        # convert the frame to grayscale, blur it, and detect circles
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5) 
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20, \
                                   param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

        if circles is not None:
            # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
            #circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles[0,:]))

            # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
            for (x, y, r) in circles:
                # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
                # corresponding to the center of the circle
                cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), r, (255, 0, 255), 2)

            # show the frame and record if a key is pressed
            cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
            # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The major change is on the `for (x, y, r) in circles:` loop to get and draw the circles. The video playback is a bit slow once added `cv2.medianBlur()`. It even further slowed down with `cv2.HoughCircles()` detection.

Here is the screenshot of the video playback with circles. Presume that you may need to modify `cv2.HoughCircles()` function parameters and the circles retrieval to meet your requirement.

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Could it be because I'm using a VM it's very slow? because@thewaywewere I tried modifying my code to your code and it is still very slow to open and crashes after showing the first frame

Comment: @Hamza Using VM is definitely slowed down. However, the problem seems on original code. It didn't run and finish on my Win10 PC and I need to kill the session. As mentioned, you may need to adjust the `cv2.HoughCircles()` parameters such as 'minRadius' and 'maxRadius'.

Comment: @Hamza by the way, please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).